# retrieve sencha touch 2 fieldsetss value

Tags: sencha-touch

I am new in sencha touch framework. I am trying to create user login at first. I would like to get username and password from the form and send to api for authentication. But I could not even able to get the field values. My LoginForm view looks like this:

```
Ext.define('NCAPP.view.tablet.LoginForm', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype:'loginForm',
id:'loginForm',
config: {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'image',
            src:'resources/img/netcenter_logo.png',
            height: 100
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'NCAPP LOGIN:',
            items: [

                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    id:'fldUsername',
                    name:'username',
                    placeHolder: 'Username'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    id:'fldPassword',
                    name:'passowrd',
                    placeHolder: 'Password'
                }

            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            id: 'btnLogin',
            text: 'Login'
        }
    ]
}
```

});

and my Login Controller:

```
Ext.define('NCAPP.controller.tablet.LoginController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',    
config: {
    refs: {   
        loginForm:'#loginForm'
    },
    control: {
        '#btnLogin':{
            tap:'onLoginButtonTap'
        }            
    }
},
onLoginButtonTap:function(){

    var values=this.getLoginForm().getValues();
    console.log(values.username); // want to see this output

    Ext.ModelMgr.getModel('NCAPP.model.User').load(1,{
        success:  function(user){

            //to do

        },
        failure: function(user){
            console.log("failed");
        }
    });    
},
init:function(application){

}
```

});

I am unsuccessful to get the value of username field. The shown error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
                return this.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
            } has no method 'LoginForm'
```

or sometime this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getValues' of undefined
```

Can anybody help me please.... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've forgotten the `()` at the end of `this.getLoginForm` in your callback. Try switching it to

```
success:  function(user){
    var values=this.getLoginForm().getValues();
                              //^^------these ones
    console.log(values.username); // want to see this output
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but there is same error even after adding () at the end of this.getLoginForm. I have two different profiles: tablet and phone. I am wondering if this is the issue?

Comment: Hmm, can you try changing your ref to `loginForm:'loginForm'`. What you have should be working, but just to make sure.